# Spring-Security-Oauth2: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/authentication/InternalAuthenticationServiceException

Tags: java, exception, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to integrate Oauth2.0 with Spring Security in web application using java based configuration. But when i trying to tun the sample application, i will thow an exception as below:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.harmeetsingh13.config.Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig$OauthWebSecurityConfigureAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter com.harmeetsingh13.config.Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig$OauthWebSecurityConfigureAdapter.clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' defined in class com.harmeetsingh13.config.Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter com.harmeetsingh13.config.Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig.clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/authentication/InternalAuthenticationServiceException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter com.harmeetsingh13.config.Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig$OauthWebSecurityConfigureAdapter.clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' defined in class com.harmeetsingh13.config.Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter com.harmeetsingh13.config.Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig.clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/authentication/InternalAuthenticationServiceException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperty
```

Following is my Spring data, Java based configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.harmeetsingh13.repo"})
@PropertySource(value="classpath:properties/db.properties")
public class SpringDataConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment; 

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    try{
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getProperty("db.driver.class"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(50);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(10);
        return dataSource; 
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getProperty("package.scan"));
    factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factoryBean.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

Follwoing is my Oauth2.0 integration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Oauth2SpringSecurityConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
@Autowired
public ClientDetailsService clientDetailService() {
    return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public UserDetailsService userDetailService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
    return new ClientDetailsUserDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
}


@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public DefaultTokenServices tokenService(TokenStore tokenStore, ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    return tokenServices;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory oAuth2RequestFactory(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
    DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
    return requestFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory, TokenStore tokenStore) {
    TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
    userApprovalHandler.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    userApprovalHandler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    return userApprovalHandler;
}

@Bean(name="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint clientAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setRealmName("Authorization/client");
    entryPoint.setTypeName("Basic");
    return entryPoint;
}

@Bean(name="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setRealmName("Authorization");
    return entryPoint;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
    OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler = new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    return accessDeniedHandler;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService,DefaultTokenServices tokenServices) {
    OAuth2AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
    authenticationManager.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    authenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    return authenticationManager;

}
//Oauth Have different ways for check user credentials like client_cridentials, password etc. This is for client_cridentials
@Bean
@Autowired
public ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter();
    accessTokenProvider.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return accessTokenProvider;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails protectedResources() {
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails protectedResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    return protectedResourceDetails;
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public static class AutorizationEndPoints extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailService;
    @Autowired 
    private DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory;
    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;
    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endPoints)
            throws Exception {
        endPoints.clientDetailsService(clientDetailService);
        endPoints.requestFactory(requestFactory);
        endPoints.userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler);
        endPoints.tokenServices(tokenService);
        endPoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public static class ResurceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("rsourceId");
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/user/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oauthAccessDeniedHandler);

    }
}

@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /*@Override
    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}

@Order(2)
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class OauthWebSecurityConfigureAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint clientAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token")
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(clientAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oauthAccessDeniedHandler);
    }
}

@Order(3)
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class WebApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?login=error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/successHandler")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
}

@Order(4)
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class AssetsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**");
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for solution. I am stuck in this problem.

Comment: Do you have spring-security-core in your classpath and is this the first exception that you see?

Comment: yes, spring-security-core is in class path and this is my first exception.

Comment: @ZoranRegvart thanks for your help, there is problem with version of spring security jars.

Comment: I have same problem what was the solution

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, which was resolved by adding the missing dependency to the `build.gradle` file.